# KewordRecognizer in Unity: MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

I am trying to experiment with a voice recognition program in unity. I am using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer. However, whenever I run the program, I receive the following error:

> MissingMethodException: Attempted to access a
>   missing method. UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer..ctor
>   (System.String[] keywords, UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel
>   minimumConfidence) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Windows/Speech.cs:221)
>   UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer..ctor (System.String[]
>   keywords) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Windows/Speech.cs:201)
>   VoiceRecognition.Start () (at Assets/VoiceRecognition.cs:23)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VoiceRecognition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] keywords = { "right", "left", "up", "down" };
    public ConfidenceLevel confidence = ConfidenceLevel.Low;
    public float speed = 1;

    public Text results;
    public Image target;

    private KeywordRecognizer recognizer;
    protected string word = "right";

    private void Start()
    {
        if (keywords != null)
        {
            recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords, confidence); #Source of error
            recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += Recognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
            recognizer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Recognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
        word = args.text;
        results.text = "You said: <b>" + word + "</b>";
    }

    #Code to move image
    private void Update()
    {
        var x = target.transform.position.x;
        var y = target.transform.position.y;

        switch (word)
        {
            case "up":
                y += speed;
                break;
            case "down":
                y -= speed;
                break;
            case "left":
                x -= speed;
                break;
            case "right":
                x += speed;
                break;
        }

        target.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (recognizer != null && recognizer.IsRunning)
        {
            recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized -= Recognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
            recognizer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to be able to move the image when the user says either "right", "left", "up", or "down", but I keep receiving a MissingMethodException, and my image keeps moving in one direction regardless of what I tell it.

Comment: Which version of unity is this?

Comment: @BugFinder, I am using Unity Version 2018.3.8f1 on my Mac.

Comment: Well, Im sorry to say it doesnt happen on my windows machine - I dont have a mac to check.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned MacOS I regret to tell you that the API Method you are using is only Available for Windows 10.

From the Documentation: `Keyword recognizer is currently functional only on Windows 10.`

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer.html